# Organizing contacts by last name for display in an alphabetized list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Contacts each have a first_name and last_name.  In my index for contacts, I display a list default_scoped by last_name in ASC order.  This works OK, but I'm looking to make it better.

I want to create an organized list in the index that groups contacts by the first letter of their last name, and I'm sort of stuck on how to get this done.  The result would look like:

```
<div class="contacts" id="contact_list_a">
  <h2>A</h2>
  <div class="contact">John Abercrombie</div>
  <div class="contact">Julie Aloters</div>
</div>

<div class="contacts" id="contact_list_b">
  <h2>B</h2>
  <div class="contact">Harry Bronson</div>
  <div class="contact">Stevie Brussels</div>
</div>

...(continues)
```

I only see two options so far because of my inexperience:

1) I could create a variable for each letter of the alphabet, and add contacts where appropriate to each.  This creates tons of calls to the DB (I'm assuming), and the abundance of variables in my controller doesn't seem elegant at all.

2) I could pull all contacts from my model into a single variable (what I'm doing now), then in my controller create a private method which iterates through the array and assigns new variables accordingly.  This still seems inefficient, but looks better to me that #1.

Could you give insight into a better way to do this?  I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've pulled your users into, say `users`, you can group them with

```
# creates a hash mapping first letter of last name to array of corresponding users
groups = users.group_by { |user| user.last_name[0].downcase }
```

In your view you can iterate through the hash as follows:

```
<% groups.each do |letter, contacts| %>
  <div class="contacts" id="contact_list_<%= letter %>">
  <h2>letter.upcase</h2>
    <% contacts.each do |contact| %>
      <div class="contact"><%= contact.full_name %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Perfect!  That does exactly what I was looking to do.  Thank you for the direction.